# How can I trigger an expensive computation at most once every 30 minutes?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

We have a system that receives a bunch of "item was updated/created/..." events, and that is responsible for doing an expensive computation on the item after it has changed. Currently this system will perform this expensive computation every time an event of the type "item was updated/created/..." arrives. However, changes to items are often made in quick succession, which thus results in a lot of (repeated) expensive computations and load on the system in a short time frame.

We would like to delay the expensive computation for 30 minutes to aggregate the various changes mad in quick succession, and at the end of that window perform the computation only once.

Thus, when the first "item X was updated/created/..." arrives we would like to start a timer for 30 minutes. Any events related to item X during that window will NOT extend the window duration of start a new window. At the end of those 30 minutes the computation is performed. If an event arrives after that cache wipe, a new window of 30 minutes is started

A similar, unrelated window might also exist at the same time for item Y. In total we have 500,000 items.

Would it be possible to help us with some pointers/advice on how to efficiently implement such an "aggregation" window? Is there an efficient data structure that could solve our problem?

We have thought of adding all the events to a database and then performing a group by query every 30 minutes via a cron, but this comes with some drawbacks:

- All item recalculations are executed at the same time (the time that the cron interval triggers), which causes a lot of load on the system. Such a fixed window interval might thus not be a good solution. We would thus prefer that the first event triggers that start of the window, and not a fixed cron.
- The overhead of storing all events in the database does not look appealing.
- Changing the window size from 30 minutes to 30 seconds might result in a lot of creates and deletes to the database.
- ...

Comment: It is hard to give a good answer to this question when we don't know which cache library you are using. A UserManagedCache is perhaps the answer.

Comment: Can you clarify if it's important that all the updated items are recalculated at the same time.

Comment: Did you mean a half million items? I am not sure if that was a typo. I added a grouping `,` for clarity. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) to store a [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) for each item, and a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to delay the execution of the expensive computation.

When an event arrives, you check if there is already a `ScheduledFuture` for the item. If there is, you do nothing. If there isn't, you create a new `ScheduledFuture`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExpensiveComputation {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void itemUpdated(String itemId) {
        futures.computeIfAbsent(itemId, id -> executorService.schedule(() -> {
            performComputation(id);
            futures.remove(id);
        }, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    }

    private void performComputation(String itemId) {
        // Perform the expensive computation here
        System.out.println("Performing computation for item " + itemId);
    }
}
```

ExpensiveComputation is a class that manages the ScheduledFutures for each item. The itemUpdated method is called when an item is updated. It checks if there is already a ScheduledFuture for the item, and if there isn't, it creates a new ScheduledFuture that will call performComputation after 30 minutes.

The performComputation method is where you would put the code for the expensive computation. After performing the computation, it removes the ScheduledFuture from the ConcurrentHashMap.

the code assumes that the events are processed in multiple threads. The ConcurrentHashMap and ScheduledExecutorService are thread-safe, so you don't need to add locks to prevent race conditions.

**Edit:**

If the computation is expensive and takes a significant amount of time, it would be better to remove the ScheduledFuture from the map before performing the computation. This way, if an update arrives while the computation is being performed, a new computation will be scheduled.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ExpensiveComputation {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> futures = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void itemUpdated(String itemId) {
        futures.computeIfAbsent(itemId, id -> executorService.schedule(() -> {
            futures.remove(id);
            performComputation(id);
        }, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
    }

    private void performComputation(String itemId) {
        // Perform the expensive computation here
        System.out.println("Performing computation for item " + itemId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot. One thought: if the expensive computation takes some time, would it be better to remove the ScheduledFuture from the map *first*? That way, any new updates that arrive while the computation is being performed will cause a new computation to be scheduled, instead of being silently skipped.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. If the computation is expensive and takes a significant amount of time, it would be better to remove the ScheduledFuture from the map before performing the computation. This way, if an update arrives while the computation is being performed, a new computation will be scheduled.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy carefully

Comment: @DavidW: It could be a false positive.

Comment: This is a good solution... for a single server. If you're running several servers, swap out the map for something universal - either a database (which will survive redeployments) or a distributed cache such as Redis, Memcache, etc (probably a better choice).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's depend of your cache system.
Generally you can set a TTL for each key and disable cache invalidation.

If you use Redis, you can set EXPIRE for you keys.
https://redis.io/commands/expire/

Answer (score -1):

i think you should use caffine

caffine store the cache in memory

then you

1、set expireAfterWrite

```
Caffeine.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(Duration.ofSeconds(30)).build()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).